# Search a person on facebook based on location, first name and country of origin

Tags: facebook, localization

I wonder if there's a way to search on facebook someone based solely on first name, current location and country of origin.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use FQL for this in: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/

Comment: the link is not working. Could you help me to search facebook users by first and last name and exact results